# architecture and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, architecture

I found a problem of multiple inheritance during developing the architecture of my program.

I have some different objects that must be displayed with GUI form. **I prefered inheritance** from Widget class **to avoid** an implemention of the methods like showed below (show, hide, setEnabled, move, etc. methods that can be used in animation):

```
void Device::show()
{
    this->widget->show();
}

void Device::hide()
{
    this->widget->hide();
}

// etc...
```

Well, I divided all objects into two groups:

- Containers (just for keeping smth, it has number and info about its content)
- Devices (real device with voltage, status codes, warnings, errors, etc.)

So, the question appears when I have entity that is both container and device (like weighing-machine because it should have info about his own number and its content and also about warnings, problems with voltage, etc.)

I thought about:

- **using interfaces** but every class implementing the interface have to realize interface's methods. And it **is not good way** to `ctrl+c`, `ctrl+v` all the code of errors handling (because it is the same for all objects) into all classes implementing the interface `ErrorAble` or `WarningAble`. Tommorow somebody will say me: "Add the new error code"... And I have to <strike>say him...</strike> make changes in all classes.
- **making one base class** but it strikes the logic when "bottle" object (container) will have voltage, error codes, warnings (as device).

And I should to do smth with the architecture. But I have no idea what to do. Could somebody suggest me something?

[image]

Comment: Beside of inheritance, you also have the concept of composition. Thus, your _weighing-machine_ could be a _container_ with display features or even the opposite (probably better for former). This may cost additional overloading for this class (what you actually tried to prevent). However, I would consider this less annoying than introduction of virtual inheritance to enable achieving this by pure inheritance.

Comment: Why not just have 2 base classes? Containers would inherit from `Container` and Devices from `Device`. Weighting machine could inherit from both.

Comment: I've added a simple diagram

Comment: @Scheff, you mean to include `Container` and `Device` not as a parent but as an internal entity of every class, don't you? I thought about the same but in this case I have to include all methods for accesing  the container or device object to deprive the possibily of changing them in all classes which use them. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Igor, because *base classes* have the same parent (see the diagram I've updated)

Comment: Entities like in [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system)? Yet another idea but not what I was thinking about. In your specific case, I would probably derive `Container` from `Device` for the cases both of them have to occur in combination. Such design tasks can drive you crazy until you get it satisfying somehow. Finally, if you've done most of the implementation, the product managers require _this_ exotic case which you didn't foresee. So, you've to add something ugly in the end. (It happened often enough in my case...) ;-)

Comment: @Bogdan you can still use multiple inheritance even if Container and Device share common base class: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance
The only problem could be chaning inheritance to virtual for Container and Device. But if it's ok, I would use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with moving `Device` and `Container` to the same level with `Widget` in objects' hierarchy and now they are not inherited from `Widget`. As a result if a object is both device and container then the class definition looks like:

```
class SomeObject : public Widget, public Device, public Container
{ /* ... */ };
```

**It helps me** to avoid *diamond inheritance*, because `Device` and `Container` have no parents.

Also: **I refused to use the composition** what was suggested in comments because:

1. `Device` is not a part of `SomeObject`.
2. `SomeObject` is one of possible *devices*.
3. `SomeObject` is one of possible *widgets*.
4. `SomeObject` is one of possible *containers*.

**What I got**: Container/Device methods are defined and implemented just once in my program (like setters and getters for container properties) and all their child objects can use them *from the box* without any delegation.